# Enigma: Inequality for two triangles

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality, vectors, geometric-inequalities

all is in the title take two triangles of sides $a,b,c$ and $x,y,z$ so we have :

\begin{align}
& (ab)^2x^2z^2+(ab)^2y^2z^2+(ac)^2x^2y^2+(ac)^2y^2z^2+(bc)^2y^2x^2+(bc)^2(x^2z^2) \\[10pt]
\leq {} & a^4(yz)^2+z^4(ab)^2+(ac)^2y^4+b^4(xz)^2+(bc)^2x^4+c^4(xy)^2
\end{align}

I have a method but it's very ugly so I would like to know a better method.

My question : What is your fastest method ?

Edit : This is my proof after some computation we find :

\begin{align}
&  a^4(yz)^2+z^4(ab)^2+(ac)^2y^4+b^4(xz)^2+(bc)^2x^4+c^4(xy)^2-[(ab)^2x^2z^2+(ab)^2y^2z^2+(ac)^2x^2y^2+(ac)^2y^2z^2+(bc)^2y^2x^2+(bc)^2(x^2z^2)]
= {} [a^2(y^2+z^2-x^2)+b^2(-y^2+z^2+x^2)+c^2(x^2+y^2-z^2)]^2-(a+b+c)[\prod_{cyc}(a+b-c)](x+y+z)\prod_{cyc}(x+y-z) & 
\end{align}

Wich is just Neuberg Pedoe inequality . But it's very ugly .

Thanks .

Comment: What is the fastest method of doing [b]what[/b]?  What question are you trying to answer?

Comment: You seem to be asking a number of related questions about inequalities apparently connected with triangles. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, but it would help if you were clearer about what you are thinking and why these inequalities seem to you to be significant.

Comment: I have a method but it's very ugly so I would like to know a better method .

Comment: Oups I make a mistake it's not $\geq$ but $\leq$...my bad.

Comment: In this case edit your post!

Comment: Look in "The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\frac{a^2b^2}{xy}\cdot\frac{x^2+y^2-z^2}{xy}+\frac{a^2c^2}{xz}\cdot\frac{x^2+z^2-y^2}{xz}+\frac{b^2c^2}{yz}\cdot\frac{y^2+z^2-x^2}{yz}\leq\frac{a^4}{x^2}+\frac{b^4}{y^2}+\frac{c^4}{z^2}.$$
Let $\xi$, $\psi$ and $\eta$ be measures-angles of the triangle $XYZ$ with sides-lengths $x$, $y$ and $z$

and let $\frac{a^2}{x}=p$, $\frac{b^2}{y}=q$ and $\frac{c^2}{z}=r$.

Thus, we need to prove that

$$2pq\cos\eta+2pr\cos\psi+2qr\cos\xi\leq p^2+q^2+r^2.$$
Now, let $\vec{p}\upuparrows\vec{XY}$ and $|\vec{p}|=p$,

$\vec{q}\upuparrows\vec{YZ}$ and $|\vec{q}|=q$

and  $\vec{r}\upuparrows\vec{ZX}$ and $|\vec{r}|=r$.

Id est, we need to prove that
$$\left(\vec{p}+\vec{q}+\vec{r}\right)^2\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Comment: Thanks Michael you make a link between Klamkin's inequality and Neuberg Pedoe inequality ! (+1)

Comment: @FatsWallers You are welcome! Good luck!